# How to calculate $\arccos (x)$?

Tags: angle

how do i calculate for example $\arccos (2/\sqrt [2] 5)$ without calculator?
I had some exercises with calculator and i could not find any good explanation for calculating per hand.

Comment: What makes you think that an exact value can be obtained?

Comment: @imranfat: did he say that ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust In the first line??

Comment: @imranfat: I don't see the word *exact* nowhere.

Comment: @YvesDaoust He doesn't talk about rounding or decimals, if someone asks "Calculate $arccos0.5$ without calculator, do you expect $1.04$ or $\pi/3$?

Comment: @imranfat: it depends if the quantity has a closed-form expression or not.

Comment: That's true, but if the OP assumes that there is a closed form, whereas in fact there may not be (as far as I know), then....

Comment: @imranfat: I don't see any assumption about a closed form in the post.

Comment: You can lookup this amazing table: http://intmstat.com/blog/2011/06/exact-values-sin-degrees.pdf; you can find more by using the angle bisection formula. But in most cases, (like your example I guess) there is no closed-form formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is no closed-formula and no calculator is allowed, about the only resort is the Taylor formula.

In your case, you are lucky, as

$$\arccos\frac2{\sqrt 5}=\arctan\frac12,$$ and you can use the Gregory's series

$$\arctan\frac12=\frac12-\frac1{3\cdot2^3}+\frac1{5\cdot2^5}-\frac1{7\cdot2^7}+\cdots$$ which gives you at least two more bits of accuracy on every term with not too painful by-hand computation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot calculate it's value without calculator.

You can only calculate values of inverse trigonometric functions for common angles viz. 0, 30, 45, 60, 90, 180, etc

Comment: There are more acute angles $x$ such that $x/\pi$ and $\cos x$ are radical numbers. ($x$ is in radians).

Comment: How do you think that the first trigonometric tables were established ?

Comment: @Yves the first trigonometric table were made by calulating the values of sin and cos from right angled triangles with one angle 0,30,45,.......respectively. A different triangle was drawn for each angle and the values of sin and cos were measured physically (since, sinx = altitude/hypo. and cosx = base/hypo)

Comment: @mikealise: I assume this was done at a time the calculators were still made of stones... Anyway, very early tables was obtained numerically, by the half-angle fomulas.

Comment: @Yves They didn't had calculators at that time (around 500bc), instead they used abacus.

Comment: @mikealise: I meant electronic calculators (by the way still made of silicon).

Answer (score 0):

$\theta = \arccos(2/\sqrt{5}) = \arctan(1/2)$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$.  This can be seen from the fact that $\exp(i\theta) = (2+i)/\sqrt{5}$ is not an algebraic integer (its minimal polynomial is $z^4-(6/5) z^2+1$), but $\exp(i \pi m/n)$ is (since it's a root of $z^{2n}-1$).